# Restrictions on label naming - Confluence 5.9

Tags: confluence

I'm receiving an error on generation of a **Page Properties Report** for label `sp-release`. Altering a couple **Page Properties** and the **Page Properties Report** to the label `sp-releas` displays those properties correctly in the report. I've looked into other causes, but want to rule out label name restrictions.

1. Is `sp-release` a restricted label name?
2. Are there any label name restrictions *(ie. cannot start with a number, no punctuation, etc.)*, and where are they documented?

Answer (score 0):

The issue was resolved by re-indexing the database via Confluence's tool. I've since found no documentation on label name restrictions .